# Convert list into one line paragraph (sed)

Tags: sed

Lets say I have a text file with a list of numbers:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

But I want it to appear as the following:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

What command do I use to do this assuming I was using SED?
Thanks. :)

Comment: Please edit your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: @Goto10, I'm a fan of your handle! Brings back memories

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
paste -sd' ' file
```

or:

```
sed -E 'H;$!d;x;:a;s/^((.).*)\2/\1 /;ta;s/.//' file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GNU `sed` you can use `-z` flag to allow processing of newlines.

```
sed -z 's/\n/ /g' myfile
```

If not, you can use `perl` in very similar manner instead:

```
perl -0pe 's/\n/ /g' myfile
```

Or better yet use `tr` to translate all newlines into spaces:

```
cat myfile | tr '\n' ' '
```

**EDIT:** if you need to replace content of the file:

- in case of `sed` you can simply add `-i` option,
- for `perl` and `tr` you can add `>myfile.bcp && mv myfile.bcp myfile` to the end of command. This will write output into temp file, and then replace initial file with it.

Comment: A small detail: in all three cases a space remains at the end of the line.

Comment: @markalex Each of your commands only outputs the change in the Terminal window. The changes are not made or applied to the file itself.

Comment: @Goto10, yes they are, since question says nothing about rewriting input file. Added description of how to rewrite file to the answer.

Comment: One thing to be aware of with sed's `-i` if portability is important: BSD sed (as found in MacOS) **requires** an argument for -i. To work the same as GNU sed on a Mac: `sed -i "" 'sed script' file ...` -- perl's `-i` is much more portable.

Comment: @glennjackman, AFAIK BSD sed doesn't support `-z` at all, and answer specifically mentions that provided solution works only with GNU sed, so it is not that actual, I think.